# Pandas to_csv slower with encoding?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm having some performance issues transforming a dataframe to csv.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time

t =time();_=pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10))).to_csv(encoding=None); print time()-t
0.159129142761
t =time();_=pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10))).to_csv(encoding='utf8'); print time()-t
1.16141009331
t =time();_=pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10))).to_csv(encoding='ascii'); print time()-t
1.13821101189
```

Why specifying an encoding type will affect drastically the performance of this method? In my particular case, I'd rather use the default value (None) but since the dataframe I need to convert contains some special chars (chinese) I cannot use the default encoding which has superior performance.

Apparently, the default encoding is "[ascii](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)" but when selected has exactly the same performance as utf8, which is the one I need to use handle non-english char.

Any idea how can I cope with speed and get around this problem?

I'm using pandas 0.16.0 and Python 2.7.9.

**EDIT:**

I've upgrade to pandas **0.16.2** as per [rth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791279/rth) suggestion, and I get better timings

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))
%timeit x.copy().to_csv(encoding='ascii')
%timeit x.copy().to_csv()
%timeit x.copy().to_csv(encoding='utf8')
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 73.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 158 ms per loop
```

Still it's half slower specifying an encoding than using the default encoding. Clearly better than the previous scenario using the 0.16.0 version, but still a tangible difference.

I'm still keen to understand if it's a bug and how can I improve it... in my case it'a difference between 10 minutes or 20 minutes!

Comment: Yes .. with a very slight variation, but reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess it that the conversion to csv outputs a string in the native encoding, and then converts it to the requested encoding, which results in an unnecessary overhead if both are the same. See this particular [line in the source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/814dbe8e206e3867a5970aaf45f4b7029ad2f59d/pandas/core/format.py#L1451), where if the encoding is not None, it used a unicode formatter even for ascii.

If you need unicode though, it makes sens that it would be a bit slower with python 2.7 than plain ascii.

Still in my case, using Python 2.7.9-r2 64 bit and pandas 0.16.1-r1, I get merely a difference of a factor of 2 between these options, not a factor of 10 that you get,

```
In [1]: x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))
   ...: 
   ...: %timeit x.copy().to_csv(encoding='ascii')
   ...: %timeit x.copy().to_csv()
   ...: %timeit x.copy().to_csv(encoding='utf8')
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 56.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
```

so this could be potentially impoved for `encoding='ascii'`.

Comment: thanks! I've upgrade to pandas 0.16.2 and I get results similar to yours (you might have a better cpu though). Still keen to understand if it's a bug or what...

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the source code. It's not a bug, mererly something that could be better optimized if `encoding='ascii'`. In your case however, since you need `encoding='utf8`, the results look reasonable.

Comment: thanks! so specifying any type of encoding will result of using pandas.core.common.UnicodeWriter instead of csv.writer resulting in been slower even if using the same econding of csv.writer. The results are MUCH better than my previous experience! Still not as quite as using the csv.writer... which I wonder is something worth flagging for, since they are doing the same thing if you're using 'ascii' as encoding, just not as efficiently.